# Extract specific strings from line in file and output to another file with modifications

Tags: bash, sed, awk, find, cut

New to linux and trying to escape doing this the hard way. I have a file ("output.txt") that contains the results of a 'find' command. Example first three lines from "output.txt":

```
/home/user/temp/LT50150292009260GNC01/L5015029_02920090917_MTL.txt
/home/user/temp/LT50150292009276GNC01/L5015029_02920091003_MTL.txt
/home/user/temp/LT50150292009292GNC01/L5015029_02920091019_MTL.txt
```

I'd like to use awk or sed (or similar) to extract two parts from the path listed for each line, and output to a new file ("run.txt") with extra information added on each line like so:

```
cd /home/user/temp/LT50150292009260GNC01; $RUNLD L5015029_02920090917_MTL.txt
cd /home/user/temp/LT50150292009276GNC01; $RUNLD L5015029_02920091003_MTL.txt
cd /home/user/temp/LT50150292009292GNC01; $RUNLD L5015029_02920091019_MTL.txt
```

I'm guessing this might also involve something like "cut", but I can't get my head wrapped around how to account for changing folder and file names.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's|^|cd |; s|/\([^/]*\)$|; $RUNLD \1|' inputfile > run
```

It says:

- insert "cd " at the beginning of the line
- for the last slash and what comes after, substitute "; $RUNLD " and the final part (captured by the parentheses)

Comment: Most complete answer, although Jens was a close second.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/^/cd /; s|/\([^/]*\)$|; \$RUNLD \1|' file
```

This prepends "cd " and replaces the last / with "; $RUNLD ". Voila!

Comment: Thanks Jens! It definitely worked as advertised, although not quite as complete as Dennis Williamson's answer.

Comment: No big deal. Dennis was one second quicker :-) Upvote appreciated, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just with bash

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
  printf 'cd %s; $RUNLD %s\n' "${filename%/*}" "${filename##*/}"
done < output.txt > run
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go about this with a loop based grep solution since I don't know `cut`, or `awk` very well haha. This does the trick:

```
while read x; do folder=$(echo "$x" | grep -o '^.*/'); file=$(echo "$x" | grep -o '[^/]*$'); echo "cd ${folder:0:-1}; \$RUNLD $file"; done < output.txt > run
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\//cd \1; $RUNLD /' file
cd /home/user/temp/LT50150292009260GNC01; $RUNLD L5015029_02920090917_MTL.txt
cd /home/user/temp/LT50150292009276GNC01; $RUNLD L5015029_02920091003_MTL.txt
cd /home/user/temp/LT50150292009292GNC01; $RUNLD L5015029_02920091019_MTL.txt
```